# PIL 5.1 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image

>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\appa\Python\miniconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 60, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

import image shows that there is no module to import

```
Import PIL
PIL.Image
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'
```

Also shows the same error

---

I have used

```
conda install Pillow
```

and it has installed **Pillow = 5.1.1**, I have also tried downgrading to **Pillow = 5.1.0**

---

Any solutions? Do I downgrade it to a lower version for it to work or is there something I have missed during installation.

Comment: please show us the actual error

Comment: @Kalyan edited to show the errors

Answer (score 1):

try upgrading pip. Use pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: I've already tried it.